# How to load json data on view fields in extjs4

Tags: json, view, grid, extjs4

i am working in extjs4. i have view as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbquestion.editWindow',
    {extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias:'widget.editWindow',
    autoScroll:true,
    store:'qb.qbquestioncategoryStore',
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 20px',
    title: '<\center>Update-Question',
    items:[
           {
               xtype:'form',
               items:[{xtype:'hidden',
                        name:'questionId'
                    },
                    {border:false,
                       layout: 'hbox',
                       margin:'10 0 0 50',
                       items:[
                    {
                       margin:'5 0 5 50',
                       xtype:'textfield',
                       fieldLabel: 'Question',
                       name: 'question',
                       width:350,
                       emptyText: 'Enter the Question'
                   },
                    { margin:'5 0 5 10',
                        xtype: 'button',
                        id:'btn5',
                        //scale:'medium',
                        width:50,
                        //name: 'add',
                        text:' Delete  ',
                        action:'delete'                                  
                  }]
                    },

                  {
                       margin:'0 0 5 100',
                       xtype:'textfield',
                       fieldLabel: 'Keyword',
                       name: 'keyword',
                       width:350,
                       emptyText: 'Enter the related word'
                   },  
                  { margin:'0 0 5 100',
                       xtype:'combo',
                       fieldLabel: 'Language',  
                       width:250,
                        store:'qb.languageStore',
                        name: 'language',
                       //queryMode:'remote',
                       displayField:'language',
                       valueField:'languageId',
                       emptyText: '---Select---'
                   },
                   { 
                       margin:'0 0 5 50',
                       xtype:'combo',
                       id:'combo1',
                       fieldLabel: 'Elementary',
                       name: 'Elementary',
                       width:250,
                       store:'qb.qbcomplexityStore',
                       //queryMode:'low',
                       displayField:'complexityl',
                       valueField:'complexityId',
                       emptyText: '---Select---'
                   },
                   { margin:'0 0 5 50',
                       xtype:'combo',
                       id:'combo2',
                       fieldLabel: 'Intermediate',
                       name: 'Intermediate',
                       width:250,
                       store:'qb.qbcomplexityStore',
                       //queryMode:'low',
                       displayField:'complexityl',
                       valueField:'complexityId',
                       emptyText: '---Select---'                                 
                   },
                   { margin:'0 0 5 50',
                       xtype:'combo',
                       id:'combo3',
                       fieldLabel: 'Expert',
                       name: 'Expert',
                       width:250,
                       store:'qb.qbcomplexityStore',
                       //queryMode:'low',
                       displayField:'complexityl',
                       valueField:'complexityId',
                       emptyText: '---Select---'
                     },
                    {
                       margin:'0 0 5 100',
                       xtype:'textfield',
                       fieldLabel: 'Option',
                       name: 'option',
                       width:350,
                       emptyText: 'Enter the option',
                       id:'opts'
                   },
                   {
                       border:false,
                       layout: 'hbox',
                       margin:'7 0 5 100',
                       items:[ { //margin:'0 0 0 15',
                                   xtype: 'checkbox',
                                    fieldLabel: 'isAnswer',
                                   name: 'isAnswer',
                                    id:'anss1'
                               },
                               { 
                                     margin:'0 0 0 10',
                                     xtype: 'button',
                                     id:'btn3',
                                     //scale:'medium',
                                     width:50,
                                     //name: 'add',
                                     text:' Add  ',
                                     action:'add'                                    
                              } ] },
                    {
                       margin:'10 0 5 100',
                       xtype:'grid',
                       id:'grid1',
                       //title : 'Educational Details',
                       store:'qb.qbquestionoptionStore',
                       columns: [
                                 { 
                                     text: 'Options',
                                     dataIndex: 'option', 
                                     flex: 1
                                 }, 
                                 {
                                     text: 'Answer', 
                                     dataIndex: 'isAnswer', 
                                     flex: 2.5
                                 }
                       ],
                       height: 100,
                       width: 350
                   },
                   { 
                        margin:'0 0 5 200',
                        xtype: 'button',
                        id:'btn4',
                        //scale:'medium',
                        width:50,
                        //name: 'add',
                        text:' Update  ',
                        action:'update'  }]}});
```

I have json data from server side as-

```
{"data":[{"questionId":"29","question":"WRHEdsgdRHW","Elementary":"Low","Intermediate":"Low","Expert":"Low","keyword":"WFHRF","language":"english","Category":[{"category":"Main","id":"1"},{"category":"GK","id":"2"}],"optionarray":[{"option":"dfbsddfb"},{"option":"sdfgsd"},{"option":"sdgsd"}]}]}
```

i want to load this data as by default entry in fields of above view during update functionality.So how to load this data? How to bind optionarray[] of json to grid with id "grid1"?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) for your Form that matches your fields. And then use [loadRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord):

> **loadRecord:** Loads an Ext.data.Model into this form (internally just calls
>   Ext.form.Basic.loadRecord) See also trackResetOnLoad.

This will bind your model to a form, later on you can use [updateRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-updateRecord) to change new data to a form fields. Here is [How to](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/forms) use forms and model binding.